# How do i get nested schema keys from mongoose main model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to get the nested attributes/keys that make up a particular model. 
For example schema:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const subDoc = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    address: {
        street: String,
        no: Number
    }
});

const mainDoc = mongoose.Schema({
    subField: [subDoc],
    phone: Number,
});
```

`console.log(mainDoc.paths)` or `console.log(mainDoc.tree)` only print "subField" and "phone" keys. If its possible get subDoc keys form mainDoc.
Like that:

```
subField
  name
  address
    street
    no
phone
```

Comment: Do you just want to print everything out?  Because you could just use a `forEach` loop with `lodash` or through the built in way to loop over the `subDocs` in the `subField` and print out the fields you want right?

Comment: Yes, but im afraid that subField dont have keys in mainDoc or i dont find them.

Comment: When you say it doesn't have keys do you mean the keys like `name` and `address` aren't present?  Because if that's the case when you run your query for the `mainDoc` you'll just need to include `populate` with a list of things you want populated in the `subDocs` and then you'll see those fields

Comment: Thanks. but i dont wanna run query.  Moad Ennagi' suggestion was answer my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consoled into `mainDoc`, this `mainDoc.childSchemas[0].schema.obj` would give you

```
{ name: [Function: String],
  address: { street: [Function: String], no: [Function: Number] } }
```